# How do I keep CSS floats in one line?

Tags: css, css-float, css-tables, stretching

I want to have two items on the same line using `float: left` for the item on the left.

I have no problems achieving this alone. The problem is, I want the two items to **stay** on the same line *even when you resize the browser very small*. You know... like how it was with tables.

The goal is to keep the item on the right from wrapping *no matter what*.

How to I tell the browser using CSS that I would rather **stretch the containing `div`** than wrap it so the the `float: right;` div is below the `float: left;` `div`?

what I want:

```
                                   \
 +---------------+  +------------------------/
 | float: left;  |  | float: right;          \
 |               |  |                        /
 |               |  |content stretching      \   Screen Edge
 |               |  |the div off the screen  /  <---
 +---------------+  +------------------------\
                                             /
```

Comment: How cool would it be if StackOverlow added a little drawing widget so we could make these diagrams with the mouse? Might be more appropriate for design-oriented SE sites... but it would be awesome nevertheless.

Comment: @JoeCool The UX SE site actually has a tool to create mockups in it, already. http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/how-do-i-add-mockups-and-or-visuals-to-my-questions

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Wrap your floating `<div>`s in a container `<div>` that uses this cross-browser min-width hack:

```
.minwidth { min-width:100px; width: auto !important; width: 100px; }
```

You *may* also need to set "overflow" but probably not.

This works because:

- The `!important` declaration, combined with `min-width` cause everything to stay on the same line in IE7+
- IE6 does not implement `min-width`, but it has a bug such that `width: 100px` overrides the `!important` declaration, causing the container width to be 100px.

Comment: This works great for two floats, but not three. Can it work for three??

Comment: The only problem is it forces a fixed minimum width.

Comment: This isn't a solution, it's just a min-width, when your content gets really small (see question) so below the 100px you have the same issue. Specially with table cells, this stays an issue.

Comment: Absolutely shocking - solved my problem instantly. I have been wrangling with this problem in a simple two column bootstrap layout with more box hacks than I can name, but this worked perfectly. Thank you for the explanation of why this work - fascinating stuff, the dom is.

Comment: This may work with divs, but I just tested it with ul/li and it doesn't work :(

Comment: If the CSS standard were revised to eliminate the need for min/max size hacks, it would be a great day.

Comment: @MattM. not to mention it's not guaranteed to work for arbitrary-length content

Comment: wow when you have to rely on a bug to ensure crossbrowser compatibility, you know the protocol is time to be updated.

Answer (score 133):

Another option is, instead of floating, to set the white-space property nowrap to a parent div:

```
.parent {
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and reset the white-space and use an inline-block display so the divs stay on the same line but you can still give it a width.

```
.child {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9g8ud31o/

Comment: Definitely the best solution I've seen.  It works for my use case but I wonder how well it's supported.  Fortunately using floats for EVERYTHING is slowly becoming a thing of the past.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? or any links atleast?

Comment: @AnirudhanJ It's not too difficult. Inline-block makes the elements flow normally with inline text (but retains some of the padding/margin abilities of the block), and you *literally* just tell the CSS not to wrap the text with the white-space: nowrap option (applying "normal" again to the child, to avoid it propagating down into everything)

Comment: How do you get the div on the right to float to the right of the screen, though? This just puts two inline-blocks next to each other that won't line break.

Comment: you can also use **letter-spacing: -3px** (or whatever value works for you) to remove the space between the inline-block elements.
PS: **better than the accepted answer**;

Answer (score 15):

Wrap your floaters in a div with a min-width greater than the combined width+margin of the floaters.

No hacks or HTML tables needed.

Answer (score 11):

Solution 1:

display:table-cell (not widely supported)

Solution 2:

tables

(I hate hacks.)

Answer (score 8):

Another option: Do not float your right column; just give it a left margin to move it beyond the float. You'll need a hack or two to fix IE6, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that floated block-level elements are the best solution to this problem?

Often with CSS difficulties in my experience it turns out that the reason I can't see a way of doing the thing I want is that I have got caught in a tunnel-vision with regard to my markup ( thinking "how can I make *these* elements do *this*?" ) rather than going back and looking at what exactly it is I need to achieve and maybe reworking my html slightly to facilitate that.

Comment: well it works for just about everything and the existing layout is based on it, I'm just trying to fix a problem with the layout breaking when you increase the text size too much OR resize the browser window smaller than 700px wide

Answer (score 2):

i'd recommend using tables for this problem. i'm having a similar issue and as long as the table is just used to display some data and not for the main page layout it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your floated element selector

```
.floated {
    float: left;
    ...
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It will prevent padding and borders to be added to width, so element always stay in row, even if you have eg. three elements with width of 33.33333%

Answer (score 0):

When user reduces window size horizontally and this causes floats to stack vertically, remove the floats and on the second div (that was a float) use margin-top: -123px (your value) and margin-left: 444px (your value) to position the divs as they appeared with floats.
When done this way, when the window narrows, the right-side div stays in place and disappears when page is too narrow to include it.  ... which (to me) is better than having the right-side div "jump" down below the left-side div when the browser window is narrowed by the user.

Answer (score -3):

The way I got around this was to use some jQuery.  The reason I did it this way was because A and B were percent widths.

HTML:

```
<div class="floatNoWrap">
    <div id="A" style="float: left;">
        Content A
    </div>
    <div id="B" style="float: left;">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floatNoWrap
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("[class~='floatNoWrap']").each(function () {
    $(this).css("width", $(this).outerWidth());
});
```

Comment: A framework for CSS? I have to -jquery for *ALL* JavaScript searches and because of a complete and utter disregard for quality we have to start explicitly searching for CSS with -jquery too? Do it right or don't do it at all.