# Autoresize ASP.NET panel having a dynamic collection of overflowing buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

Basically, inside a client control, I'm calling a query to fetch some data from a table and based on the output, i create buttons and add them from code behind to an ASP:Panel

The buttons have a CSS to flow to left one next to the other instead of displaying them as a block under each other.

CSS

```
.button_red2 
{   background:url('../../images/button_red_left.gif') no-repeat left top;  display:block;  font-size:12px;     font-weight:bold;   line-height:16px;   height:21px;    padding-left:9px; 
    padding-top:0px;  margin-bottom :2px;   text-decoration:none;   border-style:none;  color:White; width:auto;    overflow:visible ;   float:left;}
.button_red2  span
{   background:transparent url('../../images/button_red.gif') no-repeat top right; 
    padding:3px 10px 2px 0px;   border-style:none;  display:block ;}
```

In codebehind

```
                Dim locationdt = sqlDMLhelper.ExecuteQueryDT(String.Format("select distinct City from {2}{1}{2} where Staff_FK='{0}' order by City ASC", staffID, "EUS-Customer", ControlChars.Quote), cerr)

                If Not locationdt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                    For i = 0 To locationdt.Rows.Count - 1
                        Dim Sitename = locationdt.Rows(i).Item(0)

                        Dim thebutton = New LiteralControl(" <button ID='Button'" & i & " runat='server' class='button_red2' onclick='ClickedSite(""" & Sitename & """);' type='button'> <span> " & Sitename & "</span> </button> ")
                        DrilldownPanel.Controls.Add(thebutton)
                    Next
                    
                End If
```

In aspx

```
<h1> Drill Down Per Site </h1>
<div style="display:block; padding-top: 5px; " ></div>
  <asp:Panel ID="DrilldownPanel" runat="server" Height="21" > 
</asp:Panel>
```

I can safely specify height 21 as i will always have at least one button.

[image]
The container itself is set to 600 px width.

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamically set the height value of the "DrilDownPanel" given that

1. I don't know how many locations i will have (at least 1),
2. How long the names of the locations will be and at what point they thus start overflowing to the next line.

What tools are available to loop through the collection items of that panel to see how
many "lines" i've got and thus adjust the height dynamically before the rendering starts.

Or not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the panel height to "auto" it should adjust based on the contents.

Comment: doesn't do the trick. the Panel gets rendered before the buttons are being added it seems. tnxs anyway.

Comment: You might try setting the panel height to auto after adding the buttons.

Comment: If that doesn't work, your only choice is to measure the strings used for the button text and approximate the "white" space, adding things up on the fly as you make the buttons.  Depending on how you do it, it could range from a little ball-parkish to a wild guess.  Reasonably well done, your worst case should be the occasional case where the panel is one row too deep.

Comment: Tnxs Kenny for your thoughts , found the way though

Comment: Are you going to share the way through?

Comment: Hey Kenny, i've added it as the solution (<div style="clear: both;"></div>)

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the idea
[CSS floats - how do I keep them on one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266015/css-floats-how-do-i-keep-them-on-one-line)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server" >
 <ContentTemplate>
   <div class="dataBlockPurple " id="DelegationID" runat="server" 
     style="height:auto">
    <div style="width:auto;  padding-bottom:2px;">  </div> 
     <h1> Drill Down Per Site </h1>
     <div style="display:block; padding-top: 5px; " ></div>
     <asp:Panel ID="DrilldownPanel" runat="server"> </asp:Panel>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   </div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

I've added the  `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`  under the panel and it works.